# Google Tag Manager: No tag for GA4 configuration or GA4 event

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I currently have two Google Tag Manager containers, one for Android and one for iOS. The problem is that there is no tag for GA4 configuration or GA4 event.

Is there some information or documentation somewhere that clarifies the process of migrating from UA to GA4 for Mobile and also setting up custom events in the GTM? There is no measurement ID for Android and iOS to link GTM to Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase analytics events are itself is GA4 events. There are no requirements to integrate GTM for GA4 migration from GA3.

One just need to integrate firebase analytics in mobile app to pass events data in GA4. We can implement GTM to use add/modify/delete firebase event feature

Firebase Analytics: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics

Comment: Hi Meet Lukka, thank you for your answer, but we have a similar requirement with GTM(Google Tag Manager). Below is my scenario. 
My app is white labeled app, with one code base, we will deploy multiple apps based on a few configurations. Now each customer configures different GTM tags and triggers based on their features. Those events go to respective customer accounts. With Universal analytics, this was working fine. Now with the new GA4 not able to map things, create ga4 tags, etc. 
Please help me if you have any idea about how to use GTM + GA4 for mobile apps.
Thanks in advance.